# ESPP Annualized Rate of Return Calculation

Tags: rate-of-return, espp

I have a standard ESPP offering with a 15% discount on purchase price with a 3 month lookback. The length of the offering period is 3 months.
However, there is a **18 month mandatory holding period** after the stock is purchased. My question is.. How do I calculate annualized rate of return here?

Comment: How is it different than any other holding?

Comment: I don't know. Most of the discussions I'm seeing online are for ESPP with no holding period, or a 6 month holding period. Does the fact that I need to hold it for 1.5 years affect the annualized return math? I'm not sure I know how to do the math in the first place.

Comment: You don't have to hold it for 1.5 years. You *should*, if you want to maximize tax benefits, but you don't *have to*. How's the holding period mandatory? Once you purchased the shares - they are yours.

Comment: My company plan requires the shares be held for 18 months. It is not optional. I am going to doublecheck this with benefits team Monday but it is listed in multiple documents as "mandatory".

If it is required to be held for 18 months, does the math change? For simplicity, assuming that the stock stays the same price over the span of 2 years should I simply consider what the actual rate of return would be with a 15% discount?

Comment: it is highly unlikely that the stock price stays the same for 2 years. It is also very weird that the employer is forcing you to hold on to their shares. I'm not sure that is legal in the US.